# Sharing common code between directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on the core of an angular project, and want to keep behaviors as separate as possible for the sake of reuse across multiple components. An example might be using the 'iScroll' library to pull-to-refresh some content. Currently, I'm running into problems because many of these behaviors require their own scope. I thought maybe wrapping up the behaviors in a service might be the way to go, but I haven't really seen many examples of that kind of thing. So I'm wondering if that's even the right way to go. Here's a very, very simple jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/S7kC7/

```
var controls = angular.module('controls', []);
controls.service('ScrollingBehavior', function () {
    this.link = function ($scope, $element) {
        $element.addClass('scrolling');
    }
});

controls.directive('scrolling', ['ScrollingBehavior', function (ScrollingBehavior) {
    //pretend that this has its own individual scope
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            console.log("Linking scrolling");
            ScrollingBehavior.link($scope, $element);
        }
    }
}]);

controls.directive('panel', ['ScrollingBehavior', function (ScrollingBehavior) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        //pretend that this has its own individual scope
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            console.log("Linking panel");
            ScrollingBehavior.link($scope, $element);
        }
    }
}]);
```

The idea is that I'd expose certain expected methods (i.e. "link", "controller") that could be used in the other directives that require those behaviors or features. Since the scope is an object and passed by reference, it could hook in just like if the code was just copied/pasted.

Are there problems about doing it this way? Can services be considered something to serve a sort of "mix-in"? Again, I'm only asking because I've not seen really any examples of something like this.

[note: I'm not sure, but maybe this belongs on the code review site?]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 'angular' way to do this is to create a scrollingBehavior directive and tack that on to your other directives, nesting as necessary.

[Edit] Updated jsfiddle and example code with isolate scopes.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dYYk/

```
<div scrolling-with-scrolling-behavior>This should have a scroll bar</div>
<div scrolling><div scrolling-behavior>This should have a scroll bar</div></div>
<panel scrolling-behavior>This should also have a scroll bar</panel>


controls.directive('scrollingBehavior', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { 'behavior': '=' },
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            $element.addClass('scrolling');
        }
    }
});

controls.directive('scrolling', function () {
    //pretend that this has its own individual scope
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: { 'otherThing': '=' },
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            console.log("Linking scrolling");
        }
    }
});

controls.directive('scrollingWithScrollingBehavior', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { 'behavior': '=' },
        template: '<div scrolling-behavior><div scrolling ng-transclude></div><div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66dXp/ - this won't work due to quite a few of the behaviors requiring their own scope. Combining them like suggested won't work in those cases.

Comment: I see.  I would go with nesting directives instead of using a service the way you mentioned above. IMHO, much easier to follow and declarative.  http://jsfiddle.net/8dYYk/

Comment: exactly what @craig Squire said... this is still within the responsibility of directives, but you need to leverage transclusion in this type of relationship to get things working the way you intend.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch - So, in the end, I'm looking at dozens of directives such as panelThatScrolls, panelThatScrollsAndCollapses, etc. Or, come up with complex logic to pick out the appropriate template from one of dozens of templates based on attributes of the panel. Or, I manually nest them two, three, four levels deep depending on what's needed. None of this is really much better than simply copying and pasting code between directives to 'share' the behaviors.

Comment: what's better/easier for you, and what's best for your app are two totally different things.  what you suggest is a nightmare of thread usage.  Instead, you need to spend some time becoming familiar with directive inheritance, isolate scope, and transclusion.  Angular anticipated this problem, and gave you the tools to solve them. You just need to acknowledge that complicated relationships require a more sophisticated and planned approach. Sometimes being a programmer is hard :)

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @Stephen In the end you need to decide for yourself what the right course is because you know all the details of what you are implementing, but using a sound design will have far greater advantages down the road than cutting corners to reduce development time now.